# How to convert std::array<double, 100> to std::array<float, 100> ? (avoiding obvious boilerplate implementation)

Tags: c++, c++17, stdarray

Suppose I have an `std::array` of doubles and would like it converted to floats:

```
std::array<double, 100> d_array{1,2,3};
std::array<float, 100> f_array; <--convert it from d_array;
```

If using a `std::vector` it is extremely simple:

```
std::vector<float> f_array(d_array.begin(), d_array.end());
```

I know `std::array` is an aggreate type, so it seems I have to do some manual jumps on the spot in order to copy convert it to an array or is there a convenient way to do this ?

I consider `std::copy` boilerplate as well eg.:

```
std::array<float, 100> f_array;
std::copy(d_array.begin(), d_array.end(), f_array.begin());
```

This is not simpler than the vector version and cannot be [const](/questions/tagged/const):

```
const std::array<float, 100> f_array;
```

Thus ruining otherwise const-correct'ed code.

Comment: You say "If using a std::vector it is extremely simple" then why don't you?

Comment: @nada this is like saying, why use a `std::array` at all when vector exists..

Comment: Just remember that `float` has significantly smaller value ranges than `double`...

Comment: "obvious" is a difficult term imho. What is the "obvious" implementation? Do you consider using `std::copy` already as boilerplate?

Comment: @darune No, it's like saying "If *in your case* std::vector fits better, then why not use it".

Comment: @nade but thats not how i scoped the question..

Comment: What do you consider boilerplate?  Would a conversion function you can write once and stash away in a header somewhere count as boilerplate?  That's the only way I can think of to avoid extra clutter at the conversion site, but there's no standard conversion function I'm aware of.

Comment: @MilesBudnek thats an acceptable answer if its the case. A solution involving boost, c++20 is also acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While [Miles Budnek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4151599/miles-budnek)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56561912/4944425) solves OP's problem, it may fail if the array is too big (note that you are asking the compiler to generate and execute a function with N parameters). See e.g. this [example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9cyi4Bqb4wFGtnVe).

An alternative could be to use a simple `for` loop, which, since C++14, is allowed inside `constexpr` functions.

```
template< class R, class T, size_t N>
constexpr std::array<R, N> array_copy(std::array<T, N> const &src)
{
    std::array<R, N> tmp {};
    for (size_t i{}; i < N; ++i)
        tmp[i] = static_cast<R>(src[i]);
    return tmp;
}
```

Live [HERE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yKlwbk1EhiCvjh6B).

Comment: @darune Absolutely, you are right. Fixed, thanks. Funny (and very informative) how some bad tests can hide some nasty bugs.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt there's a one line solution, but in two lines:

```
std::array<float, 100> f_array;
std::copy(d_array.begin(), d_array.end(), f_array.begin());
```

See [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

Comment: That will not work with a const version eg. const std::array<float, 100>. Besides, the vector version is still simpler.

Comment: @darune If you need to initialize a `const std::array` this way, you'll have to wrap the initialization in a function or lambda that returns the `array`. The "vector version" isn't relevant. If you believe a `std::array` is better than a `std::vector` for your purpose, then you can't use `std::vector` functions. Containers have different interfaces because they are different things.

Comment: Thats what this question is all about. Im trying to avoid using lambda, boilerplate, whatever and looking for, a cleaner std (or boost, or even c++20) way to do it. Im taking you comment as: this is not possible.

Comment: "How can I build a bookshelf without using any tools? It's easy if I build a sandwich."

Answer (score 3):

You could write a simple conversion function.  There aren't any existing standard or boost functions that I'm aware of, but it's fairly simple to implement:

```
template <typename T, typename U, size_t N, size_t... Is>
std::array<T, N> array_cast(const std::array<U, N>& arr, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return { static_cast<T>(arr[Is])... };
}

template <typename T, typename U, size_t N>
std::array<T, N> array_cast(const std::array<U, N>& arr) {
    return array_cast<T>(arr, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

To use, just call `array_cast<float>(d_array)`

[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67fcf78492d11773)

Comment: Thats actually a great idea. Im leaving the question open a bit to see if others respond.

Comment: @darune: Note that this solution is restricted to values of `N` that your compiler will support the use of variadic templates.